# May I bring 3 laptops on a US Domestic flight?

Tags: usa

May I bring 3 laptops in my hand carry bag on a US Domestic flight? My flight is from Seattle Tacoma (SeaTac) connecting to SLC Airport going to my final destination MCO airport in Orlando FL.

Comment: As long as they fit within the bag. If you're worried about customs, that's only for international flights upon first arrival in the US.

Comment: I don't see how this question is remotely connected to expats (even if the OP is one) - shouldn't this be asked in travel.se?

Comment: You should most certainly double check what your airline(s) allow as a carry-on in terms of number of items, size and weight.

Comment: Delta's rules state that they cap PEDs (portable electronic devices) such as laptops at 15 per passenger

Answer (score 2):

As long as you plan to export them back home when you leave, or you already live in the US, there is no problem on the surface of things.

If you are flying from another country into the US, tne thing you may need to watch is whether your immigration officer thinks you may be bringing them to perform work.  If your visa does not permit employment, the officer may need to be convinced that you are bringing them for personal purposes.  (Remote work is likely acceptable as long as you are not working for a US company and not seeing US clients.  Things get more complicated beyond this point.)

I have traveled to the US with three computers myself (I am a computer geek and often bring projects with me to work on, especially if I am driving, not flying), but as a Canadian citizen with clear ties to Canada, there is little concern about me doing US work and I've not been hassled, but this isn't guaranteed.

Otherwise, you just need to mind the baggage size and weight limits for your airline.

Answer (score 1):

The number of laptops is not a problem.  I have regularly flown with 2 laptops and an iPad, and various other electronic bits and pieces and never had a problem.

As long as you meet carry on size restrictions you should also be fine<sup>1</sup>, although it can be a bit of a hassle getting organized when going through the TSA checkpoint.

---

<sup>1</sup> One time in Ft Lauderdale I actually saw airline staff enforce carry on size rules *prior* to passengers entering the TSA queue.  It was a surprise to see and a bigger surprise for the people who failed to meet the rules.

Comment: I brought a playstation 4 from the UK with connecting internal US flights, that was a hassle at security even tho it was just one big item!